# Database Data Types and their equivelants in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, types

I've read in forums about people having issues with certain data types when accessing a database from their website *and* windows forms application. Mostly the `decimal`, `float` and `datetime` data types.

My DB Table, for example, the Orders table consists of the following Columns. Below each column is the datatype I have chosen to use:

```
UserId     OrderId     OrderDate     InvoiceTotal      PaymentStatus     DeliveryStatus
int        int         datetime      money             bit               bit
```

My questions are:

1. Is (in Windows Forms) `DateTime.Now()` equivelant to `datetime` (in WebMatrix DB)? If not, why not? And which method would be best to work with the `datetime` datatype used in WebMatrix DB?
2. `money` Data Type: As far as I know, there is no "money" data type in Windows Forms. You can only use `Decimal` (which makes sense), but I've heard of people also using `Float`? So, which data type should I use in WinForms so that it just works properly with the `money` datatype in the DB, and how?

I'm asking these questions because in the past I've always had precision problems. Sometimes even inaccuracy problems. I've read the docs. Tutorials. Articles, etc. But I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: I'd avoid using the `money` type in SQL - use `decimal(p,s)` instead, and specify required precision and scale. `money` has weird rounding rules (it rounds to 4 decimal places, even in the middle of a longer calculation) which can strike at the oddest of times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, better clear up some confusion:

1. Windows Forms is a technology built on top of the .NET Framework. When you describe `DateTime.Now`, you're discussing types from the base class library, not Windows Forms.
2. WebMatrix DB, is in fact, Sql Server Compact.

You might not of come across answers through search if you're making the mistake of confusing tools with the framework itself.

If you need a way to compare .NET data types with Sql data types, it's worth looking at the [MSDN Library Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) which discusses this very thing.

For your specific questions:

1. `DateTime` can be used with `datetime` in most scenarios, however Sql Server cannot deal with exceptional date ranges (e.g. < 01/01/1753). I can't imagine many scenarios you would need to go less than that, but it's worth a note.
2. You're right, there is no `money` data type in the **base class library**, the compatible .NET data type is `Decimal`. Decimal is a fixed-precision data type which means that all values can be represented and stored with a range, whereas `Float` is an approximate-number data type, and *could* be prone precision issues.

There are arguments for using both, for both accuracy and performance reasons, it depends what your application is design to do.